# How could I avoid this raw pointer with this OpenMP critical section?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, openmp

I have a `std::deque<std::reference_wrapper<MyType>> mydeque`. I need a function that returns the front value (as a plain reference) and pops it from the queue. As `std::deque` are not thread safe, access should be protected (I'm using OpenMP).

I came up with the ugly code below. It looks very bad having such advanced structures and then falling back to a raw pointer.

```
MyType & retrieve() {
  MyType* b;
  #pragma omp critical(access_mydeque)
  {
    b = &(mydeque.front().get());
    mydeque.pop_front();
  }
  return *b;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot return *within* the critical section, but I also cannot declare a reference(_wrapper) *before* the critical section (because it must be assigned to something)... Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Could you explain/show a bit more of how you're using `mydeque` inside the parallel region?

Comment: @Zboson I have one thread that push_back and another one that pop_front. I was getting random crashes without protecting those accesses.

Comment: I understand why it would crash. I'm wondering if you have the wrong approach which is why I would like to see a bit more code. For example if I use `std::vector` I would make private versions for each thread and then merge them. I would like to see how you're using `mydeque` in the parallel region.

Comment: @Zboson It is just a producer-consumer scheme, without the issues related to synchronization (that is solved elsewhere in the code). I just need to protect the shared LIFO stacks, and in particular I do not like the code above (although it works well). Posting some readable code here would be way too much work...

Comment: Well If your code is doing what you want but you don't like how the code looks I'm afraid somebody else will have to answer your question then. I'm not good with syntactic sugar...

Comment: I assume that `_front_bunches` and `mydeque` are indeed the same object somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution I can think of involves using an `omp_lock_t` instead of the `critical` construct and a RAII class managing the `omp_lock_t` ownership:

```
class LockGuard {
public:  
    explicit LockGuard(omp_lock_t& lock) : m_lock(lock){
        omp_set_lock(&m_lock);
    }

    ~LockGuard() {
        omp_unset_lock(&m_lock);
    }

private:
  omp_lock_t& m_lock;
};
```

Then you can either modify the code you already have into something like:

```
MyType & retrieve() {
    LockGuard guard(mydeque_lock);
    auto b = mydeque.front();
    mydeque.pop_front();
    return b;
}
```

or better, write your own thread-safe container that aggregates the lock and the `std::deque`:

```
template<class T>
class MtLifo {
public:
    MtLifo() {
       omp_init_lock(&m_lock);
    }

    typename std::deque<T>::reference front_and_pop() {
        LockGuard guard(m_lock);
        auto b = m_stack.front();
        m_stack.pop_front();
        return b;
    }

    void push_front(const T& value) {
        LockGuard guard(m_lock);
        m_stack.push_front(value);
    }


    ~MtLifo() {
        omp_destroy_lock(&m_lock);
    }

private:
   std::deque<T> m_stack;
   omp_lock_t m_lock;
}
```

Comment: Cool, that looks like a mutex in OpenMP! I should study OpenMP a bit more in depth (= go beyond #pragmas)!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use TBB's parallel data structures https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506076 (though since there is no concurrent_deque they may not be perfect for you :-( ).

They do not require that you also use TBB to describe the parallelism aspects of your code, so can be mixed into an OpenMP code. (Of course, since you're using C++ you might find TBB's approach to scalable, composable, parallelism more friendly than OpenMP's, but that's a separable decision).